Capturing data from AJAX-loaded modals using jQuery and JavaScript, encountering issues with capturing data from previous modals when opening new ones
I have a modal where I use AJAX with jQuery and JavaScript to make a GET request and display some data. Within this modal, there's a button that, when clicked, captures some data. I've added a console.log to verify if the data is being captured, and indeed it is. However, when I close this modal, open another one, and repeat the same steps, clicking the button shows in the console.log that it has captured data from previous modals along with the current one. I need it to only capture data from the current modal.
/* Evento que abre o modal dinamicamente */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btnBatchModal').click(function() {
                var cd_regiao = $(this).data("cd-regiao");
                var nr_grupo = $(this).data("nr-grupo");
                var cd_lote = $(this).data("cd-lote");
                var ano_base = $(this).data("ano-base");
                var urlBatch = 'show/' + cd_regiao + '/' + nr_grupo + '/' + cd_lote + '/' + ano_base;

                $.ajax({
                    url: urlBatch,
                    method: "get",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var batch = JSON.parse(data);
                        var formData = null;

                        $('#tableAssoc').empty();

                        $('#showBatchHeader h1.modal-title').html('Lote ' + batch.showBatches[0].cd_capa_de_lote +
                            ' - ' + 'Grupo ' + batch.showBatches[0].nr_grupo + '/' + batch.showBatches[0].cd_regiao);

                        var count = 0;

                        batch.showBatches.forEach(function(item) {

                            if (item.nr_cpf == null) {
                                item.nr_cpf = ' - ';
                            }

                            //ABA ASSOCIADOS
                            var htmlAssoc =
                                `   <hr class="border border-dark border-2">
                                    <div class="col-2" id="nr_cpf_${count}">
                                        <p>${item.nr_cpf}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2" id="nr_registro_${count}">
                                        <p>${item.nr_registro}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4" id="nm_associado_${count}">
                                        <p>${item.nm_associado}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2" id="dt_validade_${count}">
                                        <p>${moment(item.dt_validade).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2" id="fl_ativo_${count}">
                                        <p>${item.fl_ativo}</p>
                                    </div>`;

                            $('#tableAssoc').append(htmlAssoc);
                            count++;
                        });

                        //ABA INFORMACOES REGISTRO
                        $('#qt_inclusao').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_inclusao);
                        $('#qt_renovacao').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_renovacao);
                        $('#qt_retorno').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_retorno);
                        $('#qt_transferido').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_transferido);
                        $('#qt_segunda_via').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_segunda_via);
                        $('#qt_credencial_pai_responsavel').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_credencial_pai_responsavel);
                        $('#qt_credencial_mae').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_credencial_mae);
                        //$('#qt_credencial_impressa').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_credencial_impressa);

                        //ABA VALORES
                        $('#vl_desconto').html('R$ ' + batch.showBatches[0].vl_desconto);
                        $('#vl_cota_registro').html('R$ ' + batch.showBatches[0].vl_cota_registro);
                        $('#qt_distintivo_anual').html(batch.showBatches[0].qt_distintivo_anual);
                        $('#vl_distintivo_anual').html('R$ ' + batch.showBatches[0].vl_distintivo_anual);

                        //METODO DE PAGAMENTO
                        if (batch.showBatches[0].nr_boleto == null && batch.showBatches[0].dt_confirmacao_cartao == null) {
                            $('#accordionMtdPagamento').hide();

                        } else {
                            $('#accordionMtdPagamento').show();
                        }

                        if (batch.showBatches[0].nr_boleto) {
                            $('#nr_boleto').html(batch.showBatches[0].nr_boleto);
                            $('#vl_boleto').html('R$ ' + batch.showBatches[0].vl_boleto);
                            $('#dt_vencimento').html(moment(batch.showBatches[0].dt_vencimento).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
                            $('#dt_pagamento').html(moment(batch.showBatches[0].dt_pagamento).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

                            if (batch.showBatches[0].nr_parcelas == null) {
                                $('#nr_parcelas').html(' - ');
                            } else {
                                $('#nr_parcelas').html(batch.showBatches[0].nr_parcelas);
                            }

                            $('#rowBoleto').show();
                            $('#rowBoleto1').show();
                        } else {
                            $('#rowBoleto').hide();
                            $('#rowBoleto1').hide();
                        }

                        if (batch.showBatches[0].dt_confirmacao_cartao) {
                            $('#vl_cartao').html('R$ ' + batch.showBatches[0].vl_cartao);
                            $('#dt_confirmacao_cartao').html(moment(batch.showBatches[0].dt_confirmacao_cartao).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
                            $('#rowCartao').show();
                        } else {
                            $('#rowCartao').hide();
                        }

                        if (batch.showBatches[0].ds_observacao_descontos) {
                            $('#ds_observacao_descontos').html(batch.showBatches[0].ds_observacao_descontos);
                            $('#accordionObs').show();
                        } else {
                            $('#accordionObs').hide();
                        }

                        $('#showBatchModal').modal("show"); //abrir modal


                        /* Evento que libera os lotes pelo botão */
                        $('#btnBatchUnlock').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            formData = {
                                'cd_capa_de_lote': batch.showBatches[0].cd_capa_de_lote,
                                'nr_grupo': batch.showBatches[0].nr_grupo,
                                'cd_regiao': batch.showBatches[0].cd_regiao,
                                'dt_base_calculo': batch.showBatches[0].dt_base_calculo,
                            }
                            var urlBatchUnlock;

                            // $.ajax({
                            //     url: urlBatchUnlock,
                            //     method: "post",
                            //     success: function(data) {}
                            // });
                            
                            
                        });

                        console.log(formData);

                        $("#showBatchModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
                            formData = null;
                        });

                        /* Fim evento que libera os lotes pelo botão */
                    },
                });
            });
        });
        /* Fim evento modal */

I've tried modifying the code several times, including clearing the array when the modal opens or closes, but nothing seems to work.I need it to capture ONLY the data from the current modal. I've tried several attempts to clear the array, but it seems like it doesn't recognize that.
